# Complex UITableView/UITableViewCell and performance

Tags: ios, uiview, uitableview, calayer

I have a tableview with a complex form of subviews.

above is a header (not part of the UITableview and no problem with that) but everything under that get's rendered very slow when there are a lot of rows.  Every cell has a label and a background image with several possible images like the blue border and the triangle.

In general, I'm looking for the best possible solution to do this kind of complex UITableView rendering.

Maybe Working with CALayer?

[image]

Comment: Maybe not the problem, but are you trying this on the simulator?, sometimes tableview scrolling is slow for me on sim, but it is fine on device.

Comment: For each column in the image above (A-G) do you create a new UITableViewCell or do you try to re-use an existing one?

Comment: Yeah, you can pretty much reuse everything here and just change the labels and/or background images.

Comment: Also, do you create a `UITableViewCell` (which has some overhead) for every cell in this grid, or do you create one for each row in the grid, then adding `UIView` "cells" to that `UITableViewCell` as subviews? Not sure which would be more performant, my guess would be the one with fewer `UITableViewCells`.